# Generate war from Play Framework

Tags: playframework

Is there a plugin that can be used to generate war from a Play Framework Project?

```
c:\>myproject>play war
```

Command mentioned above does the war generation but when deployed on Weblogic or Websphere, it does not get deployed.
Tried it in the past but was not successful in getting the deployment successful.

Answer (score 1):

In case your project is based on play framework 2.x this plugin worked for me in the past: 
https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

Have been successfully using it with play version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Referred : https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

### Create and Deploy  as WAR

Two files were modified to get the same working / to enable deployment of the Play App as a WAR.

```
1) under "/playframeworkProject/project/plugins.sbt" add the following at the bottom

    // Added for WAR deployment support
    addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.2-beta1")

2) under "/playframeworkProject/project/Build.scala"

    import com.github.play2war.plugin._

Make following code changes.

    object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    .
    .
    .

    lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
     .settings(Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)
    .
    .
    resourceDirectory in IntegrationTest <<= baseDirectory /"it/resources",
      Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.0")
    .
    .
    }
```

Should finally look something like >>>

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  import com.mckesson.builder.Resolvers._
  val appName         = "YourPlayProjectName"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT" 


   val appDependencies = com.companyname.builder.Dependencies.YourPlayProjectName

   resolvers :=  com.companyname.builder.Resolvers.XYZResolvers

    lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
     .settings(Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)
     .settings(  playCommonSettings: _*
                ).configs( IntegrationTest ).settings( Defaults.itSettings :_*)
         .settings(scalaSource in IntegrationTest <<=  baseDirectory /"it" ,
          scalaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory /"test",
          resourceDirectory in IntegrationTest <<= baseDirectory /"it/resources",
      Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.0")



}
```

### Convert YourPlayProjectName to WAR

Re-build project's via sbt clean publish-local
cd to YourPlayProjectName directory
Run play war or sbt war to generate a WAR

### Deploy the app as a WAR to Tomcat

Go to YourPlayProjectName/target/ to find the WAR

Re-name the WAR to ROOT.war

Copy it your Tomcat 7’s webapps folder

Note that you need to define CATALINA_HOME environment variable and add it/bin to your Path

Example: C:>echo %CATALINA_HOME%  C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.40
     4. Start your database

```
 5. Start Tomcat 7 with this command from your command prompt (no specific location as long as your CATILANA_HOME is set correctly in your environment variable) catalina start

 6. Start your other dependencies if any to make sure your application works.
```

In the browser, hit http://:8080 to see your application working and deployed successfully.

Enjoy!!

Comment: I don't seem to find the Build.scala file anywhere. Are you sure about that?

Comment: it's an alternative to build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

This page will certainly help you to understand about the configurations required for generating war files...
https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Configuration

Generally you have to make changes at places for adding configurations:
1. `plugins.sbt(project-root/project/)`
2. `build.sbt (project-root)`

---

## for play 2.4 and above

1. plugins.sbt

`addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.4-beta1")`

2. build.sbt

   ```
   import com.github.play2war.plugin._

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "com.github.play2war" % "play2-war_2.9.1" % "0.8.2"   # Change version
   )

    Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings

    Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5" # Change as per your requirement(3.0 or 3.1 etc)
   ```

   addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.4-beta1")
3. Run [ sbt war]