# Deploying Java Play app on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, playframework, sbt

I'm building a Java Play (2.5) application and am struggling to figure out how to deploy this on a Tomcat server. Normally I would transfer a .war file to the webapps folder of my server and live happily ever after, however when running 'sbt dist' as shown in [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) it creates a jar, binary etc but no .war.

Does anyone know an easy way to either get a .war file of the application which I can easily put into the webapps folder, or any other simple way to get my application built and served from a server?

Comment: Look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935539/generate-war-from-play-framework

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this

Comment: @DanielaVladimirova - I've had a look over the link you've provided and several others on SO but I'm still unable to find a clear answer on how to install and use the Play2War plugin. Sorry if it sounds a bit dumb, I can't get it working from the information on the GitHub page either. Do you know how to install and configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad! Play2war is not supporting the 2.5 version of Play (yet)
    `Play 2.5.x          : Not supported yet`

You better stick to the SBT specific plugins, don't worry SBT is powerful tool but it seems complex at first.

This plugin looks good to me for what you need to do: https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/2.2.md

If this also doesn't work, look at all the SBT community plugins that are listed here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html